# Retain soft-input/IME state on Orientation change

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I'm having a small user experience issue in my app;

When changing from landscape to portrait (or portrait to landscape) with the Soft Keyboard open, the keyboard hides.

What I want to do is to stop the keyboard hiding on orientation change.

(**Edit** - I don't want to force the keyboard open, if the keyboard was hidden before the orientation change, I want it to stay hidden - I want to *retain* the keyboards open/closed state).

I've looked around for an answer and it seems adding `stateUnchanged` to the `windowSoftInputMode` options in the manifest for the `Activity` is the correct way to solve this (as described in the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

The problem is this seems to have absolutely no effect.

Does anybody know of any caveats to this functionality? Does it perhaps not work if the `EditText` which is focused is in a `Fragment`?

Comment: It's a shame no-one has answered this. I'm having a similar issue where it only doesn't work for a Samsung s6 in a dialog fragment.

Comment: I have almost the exact same problem. I posted a question too:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173171/keyboard-dismissed-on-rotation-to-landscape-mode-android

Comment: Do you have a solution to this problem now?

Comment: Nope, never managed to solve

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Same problem, my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477115/keyboard-disappears-on-orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code and it will work :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: This forces the keyboard to be visible - What I want to do is retain the keyboard state across orientation change.

Comment: @Graeme you probably can not. It is up to the keyboard implementation whether or not it wants to retain the previous state after a configuration change.