# Keyboard dismissed on rotation to landscape mode Android

Tags: android, android-orientation

Running into a strange problem.

When I'm on portrait and have the keyboard visible and rotate to landscape, the keyboard is dismissed (with or without text in the `EditText`). The text is also retained on rotation.

When I'm on landscape and have the keyboard visible and rotate to portrait, the keyboard continues to be visible on portrait.

Any idea what could be going wrong? I'm not handling configChanges myself and I don't intend to.

I also tried using `stateUnchanged | adjustResize` in the XML and that did not change anything.

Comment: I ran into same issue. Have you found anything useful?

Comment: Seeing as well. Any updates?

Comment: Wait a second. Are you doing anything with toggling the soft input using InputMethodManager or the IMM flags? Ie.. HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, SHOW_FORCED, etc?