# Keyboard disappears on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-orientation

I have a fragment with EditText and add it into the layout using transactions. But if I rotate to landscape the soft keyboard disappears.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer) == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentWithEditText())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I want keyboard state still unchanged after rotate using fragment transactions. Because if I don't use transactions, but add a fragment straight in the layout, the keyboard not disappeared.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:tag="fragmentWithKeyboard"
        android:name="com.test.FragmentWithEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I already tried to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"` or `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`, but didn't help.

Also I wrote a sample app with this behavior https://github.com/anton9088/FragmentAndKeyboard

**Similar questions:**

[Retain soft-input/IME state on Orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182749/retain-soft-input-ime-state-on-orientation-change)

[Keyboard dismissed on rotation to landscape mode Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173171/keyboard-dismissed-on-rotation-to-landscape-mode-android)

Comment: use this android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" not working, but if I use stateAlwaysVisible keyboard appeared in portrait, but not in landscape

Comment: @Radhey Strangely this works only if parent Activity has EditText in its layout. If there is only EditText in fragment and it has focus and keyboard is shown, after orientation change, keyboard hides.

Comment: @user1275972 Are you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your EditText's attribute [freezesText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText) value to true.

You can also add focus in onViewCreated callback manually

Comment: The problem is not in focus, EditText has focus both before and after rotate

Comment: @user1275972 but it is losing focus during fragment pause. This may trigger keyboard to disappear as there is no Editable widget during fragments recreation. But strangely it is working if EditText is in Activity with configChanges in its manifest.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The problem is that our view should has `windowSoftInputMode` set to `stateUnchanged` which means:

> The soft keyboard is kept in whatever state it was last in, whether visible or hidden, when the activity comes to the fore.

In an activity it can be obtained by simply change in `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding this:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"/>
```

Unfortunately it will not work for fragments.

### Solution for DialogFragment

If your fragment is a `DialogFragment` you can obtain it by adding this code to your `onCreateDialog` method while you have already created a dialog:

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
if (window != null) {
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change below lines in your manifest i am sure it will helps you

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivityName"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

So replace your

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`
To
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: It's working, but I prefer don't use configChanges to avoid manually handle orientation changes